# Size of spaces left before and after title chapters in ConTeXt

Tags: sectioning, context

How much space is left before and after title chapters, considering that the parameters before and after have been set as `[before=,after=,]`?

Are these spaces related to the font size of the title itself?

Layout example:

```
(space before)
Chapter 1. My Chapter
(space after)
```

Even though I have defined the space before and after as no space, ConTeXt seems to leave some blank space.

Comment: Could you elaborate your question. I have a hard time understanding what you are asking.

Comment: The `\setuphead` command does not take `spacebefore` and `spaceafter` keys. You have to set these space using `before={\blank[force,1cm]}, after={\blank[3cm]}`, etc.

Comment: My doubt is if there is any space add even if I don't set any using before and after commands.

Comment: Please add a minimal working example to show what you tried and what the actual output was

Answer (score 1):

What is inserted between the last line of the preceding paragraph and the title of a new chapter, when both `before` and `after` are set to blank, is exactly `\lineskip`.  Also, there is always a `\strut` in the title.

To illustrate this I insert a rule of with `\lineskip` right between the two lines mentioned before.

```
\def\htlineskiprule{%
  \smash{\color[red]{%
      \vrule height \dimexpr\ht\strutbox+\lineskip depth -\ht\strutbox width 2cm}}%
}
\def\dplineskiprule{%
  \smash{\color[red]{%
      \vrule height -\dp\strutbox depth \dimexpr\dp\strutbox+\lineskip width 2cm}}%
}
\definehead[chapter][page=no,before=,after=]
\starttext
\vrule Lorem\vrule ipsum\vrule
\startchapter[title=\vrule Test\llap{\htlineskiprule}\llap{\dplineskiprule}\vrule]
\vrule Lorem\vrule ipsum\vrule
\stopchapter
\stoptext
```

[image]

Comment: You can also try a basic example with `\showboxes` to visualize the boxes or `\showallmakeup`. Also see `trac-vis.mkiv` for some other visualizers.